# Binding doesn't work inside a JQuery callback

Tags: asp.net, binding

I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" ID="JOB_CODETextBox" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("JOB_CODE") %>' readonly="readonly" 
onclick="$('#basic-modal-content').modal(
{
   appendTo:'form', persist: true,
   onClose: function (dialog) 
            {
                document.findElementById('<%= JOB_CODETextBox.ClientID %>').value = 'value'; 
                $.modal.close();
            } 
} );" />
```

The problem is, the binding `'<%= JOB_CODETextBox.ClientID %>'` doesn't work, it returns the same binding expression after renderign instead of replace it with the actual client id!

Any help !!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use codeblocks (`<%%>`) inside a server side control in this manner.

You are trying to render server side code in a control that is *already* server side.

Binding Expressions (`<%#%>`) are designed to work within server side controls and don't have this issue.

Why can't you bind the click event outside the control declaration, in a javascript section? That will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for replay, with <%#%>: same issue still exists.

Comment: @Homam - Without seeing the code behind for these, it is very difficult to tell what might be wrong.

Comment: I took the script out to a javascript section, and it works. thanks.